# Remove double domain name from url via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How I can remove doubled domain name via htaccess rules, from below string:

```
https://example.com//example.com/uploads/posts/2018-05/thumbs/1389750815_20180207_103401-10.jpg
```

to make this URL as below:

```
https://example.com/uploads/posts/2018-05/thumbs/1389750815_20180207_103401-10.jpg
```

The problem that all RewriteRules that I saw can remove domain name fully, but I need to remove it only once!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was simple:

```
RewriteRule (.*)example.com/(.*) $1/$2
```

Thanks to all!